# Back button in chrome doesn't work after submitting a form and following a href back to that form

Tags: html, asp.net, google-chrome

I'm building a workflow-like webapp and I'm having a problem that can be summarized by the following:

We have three pages: page1, page2 and page3

```
page1 --[POST]-> page2 --[POST]-> page3
```

page3 contains hrefs to page1 and page2. Now what happens is when I follow a href to page1, and I hit Back; I'm on page3. Now when I follow the href to page2, and I hit Back; I'm still on page2, while I'd expect to be at page3.

This happens on chrome, not in IE, I haven't tested any other browsers. For the life of me I can't figure out why Chrome behaves like it does. How do I make Chrome behave the way IE does? Or is IE in the wrong, and should I explicitly tell the browsers what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually a bug in chromium: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=340277.

You can work around it `by modifying the url in the <a href> in any way (e.g., adding a spurious "#" or a bogus url parameter)`